# How to delete Bundle Product in Magneto

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I want to delete bundle product in Magento

I have find some tutorial to delete Products in Magento.

But I am little confused to use that code for bundle products also because as there is dependency of Bundle products with simple products.

Below is my code -

```
$entity_id = trim($data[0]);

        try
            {
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($entity_id)->delete();

            } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
            {
                Mage::log("Unable to delete Product - Entity ID: ". $entity_id);
            }
```

Can anyone please suggest how to delete bundle products along with its simple product.

Comment: you want to delete some specific bundle products or all bundle product of your store?

Comment: @AmitRajput Some specific Bundle Products by its entity_id. I have entity id of both simple and bundle products.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below script to Delete bundle product and its associated simple products:

```
//bundled product id
$id = 887;  
$itemIds = array();
$itemIds[] = $id;

//Fetch all asscoiated products of bundle item
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($id);
$collection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
    ->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product), $product);

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $itemIds[] = $item->getId();
}

// Delete all products
foreach ($itemIds as $productId) {
    try {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->delete();
        echo "<br>Product Deleted: ". $productId;   
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<br>Unable to delete Product - Entity ID: ". $entity_id;
    }
}
```

If you are using standalone script to delete products. you need to set `isSecureArea` registry as below in before script code.

```
Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
```

Comment: I have some fix simple products like 10 products which we sell with other simple products by making it as a Bundle Product. So we dont want to delete fix simple product. Is this possible with your script ? Because As per my understanding it delete all Associated Products with Bundle Products.

Comment: You can exclude fix simple products ID from `$itemIds` array

Comment: What if I directly Pass Entity_id (Simple and Bundle ID) which I want to delete

Comment: But thats the main problem whenever I pass entity_id it doesn't delete product. please check my code in question.

Comment: Try to use `Mage::register('isSecureArea', true); ` on the top of your script